# C# Remove line of data from List

Tags: c#

Here is my List declaration:

```
public List<CharactersOnline> charactersOnline = new List<CharactersOnline>();
public class CharactersOnline
{
    public int connectionId;
    public int characterId;
    public string characterName;
}
```

Here is how i add lines into this list:

```
charactersOnline.Add(new CharactersOnline() { connectionId = cnnId, characterId = charId, characterName = name });
```

Here is how i think i can remove one line by just poiting one of the parameters:

```
    private void CharacterLogout(int charId)
    {
        charactersOnline.Remove(new CharactersOnline() { characterId = charId });
    }
```

Can i remove all the data on the line of the list by just pointing only one of the parameters or this is just going to delete the data for `characterId` only ?

I need to know how can i delete the whole line of this list.

Comment: you mention you want to remove a line of data in the title, but your code is attempting to remove one character

Comment: The problem here is you create a `new CharactersOnline` object.  Because `CharactersOnline` is a `class`, two objects are not necessarily equal even if they share the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to find it and then remove it:

```
var charactersOnline = new List<CharactersOnline>();
var target = charactersOnline.SingleOrDefault(x => x.characterId == 1);
charactersOnline.Remove(target);
```

So your method will be like this:

```
private void CharacterLogout(int charId)
{
    var target = charactersOnline.SingleOrDefault(x => x.characterId == charId);
    charactersOnline.Remove(target);
}
```

Comment: Why the null checking?

Comment: @NotADeveloper because I thought it is needed but yes it is not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach in more functional way.

```
private void CharacterLogout(int charId)
{
    charactersOnline = charactersOnline.Where(line => line.characterId != charId)
                                       .ToList();
}
```

Notice, that approach above will remove all lines with given `charId` value.

Your approach will not work because `Remove` method will search for element with same reference as given item to remove.
The line `new CharactersOnline() { characterId = charId }` will create new instance of object which reference not exists in the list.
So for removing correct item you should find it first.

```
var indexesToRemove = 
    charactersOnline.Select((line, index) => (Id: line.characterId, Index: index))
                    .Where(item => item.Id == charId)
                    .Select(item => item.Index);

foreach (var index in indexesToRemove)
{
    charactersOnline.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove item from List based on condition

```
charactersOnline.Remove(charactersOnline.Single(s => s.characterId = charId) );
```